# Why AES is not decrypting my encrypted text?

Tags: python, pycrypto, ecb

does ecb mode have bugs?
why my program not working even I did everything... I am stuck please help.

**Text I encrypted :** hello world

**My attempt :**

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

key = '0123456789abcdef'
#this is the password that we are going to use to encrypt and decrpyt the text 

def encrypt(text):
    global key
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    
    if len(text) %16!=0:
        while not len(text)%16==0:
            text=text+" "
    
    encrypted_text =cipher.encrypt(text)
    return encrypted_text.strip()


def decrypt(text):
    global key
    decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    
    if len(text)%16!=0:
        while len(text)%16!=0:
            text=str(text)+" "
    
    return decipher.decrypt(text).strip()
   
text=input("Enter encrypted text here : ")
#b'XhXAv\xd2\xac\xa3\xc2WY*\x9d\x8a\x02'

print(decrypt(text))
```

**Input :**

```
b'XhXAv\xd2\xac\xa3\xc2WY*\x9d\x8a\x02'
```

**output :**

```
b"yR\xca\xb1\xf6\xcal<I\x93A1`\x1e\x17R\xbb\xc8(0\x94\x19'\xb3QT\xeb\x9b\xfe\xc8\xce\xf4l9\x92\xe8@\x18\xf2\x85\xbe\x13\x00\x8d\xa8\x96M9"
```

**Required Output :**

```
hello world
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? The `input` functions do completely different things between the two. Also ECB is not secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not pad cipher text in decryption. Note that you might need to remove padding after decryption and not before it.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

key = '0123456789abcdef'
#this is the password that we are going to use to encrypt and decrpyt the text 

def encrypt(text):
    global key
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    if len(text) %16!=0:
        while not len(text)%16==0:
            text=text+" "
    encrypted_text =cipher.encrypt(text)
    return b64encode(encrypted_text).decode('UTF-8')

def decrypt(text):
    global key
    text = b64decode(text) # decode before decryption
    decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    return decipher.decrypt(text).decode('UTF-8')

text = input("Please enter your text: ")
ciphertext = encrypt(text)
print(f'Ciphertext: {ciphertext}')
print(f'Decrypted ciphertet: {decrypt(ciphertext)}')
```

And here is the result:

```
Please enter your text: hello world
Ciphertext: WGhYQXbSrKPCV1kqnYoCDQ==
Decrypted ciphertet: hello world
```

UPDATE:
You can also encode ciphertext by calling `b64encode` in `base64`, in this case you need to decode before decryption by calling `b64decode`.
It is recommended to use codings like base64 to make it easier for transferring ciphertext in network and Internet.

Comment: why it is not working (ValueError) if I give ciphertext as input?? ```ciphertext=bytes(input("Enter ciphertext here : ), encoding="utf-8")```

Comment: @RatnapalShende2 check my answer again.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! @Pouya Esmaeili